# How to use ffmpeg to make P frames reference to only the beginning I frame in a GOP?

Tags: ffmpeg

Normally, a P frame references to the I frame and the preceding P frames. However, I want to get IPPPPPP... and all the P frames reference to only the I frame within a GOP. Is it possible to achieve it using ffmpeg? Thanks.

Comment: Which codec are you using?

Comment: and more importantly, why would you want that? Typically, handicapping a codec using random restrictions like this will have pretty severe quality implications...

Comment: We are using H.264. If H.264 doesn't support it, we are open to any other codec. Actually, we want to see how much does the bitrate grow with such a restriction. This restriction makes video compression worse, but it is helpful during the video transmission in our scheme. Do you have any idea how to achieve such a coding method? Thank you.